# button shows second border (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a layout-grid, but can't seem to get it right...

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/atjwV/).

- The button shows this weird second border when I try to vertically center his text, by using `display: table-cell;`.
- Idealy, the button must have a max-width of 300px, but that's not working either... It continues to grow with the window

Anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to be working, there's nothing in the javascript box.

Comment: It's apparently IE hostile... Works in Firefox. Not sure about Chrome. Open up debug tools (F12) and inspect the button. You'll see there's an inner piece that has a border as well as an outer piece.

Comment: Yeah,I know, what the button does is irrelevant. The question is about the grey button in the middle ("Click me"). (tested with Chrome)

Comment: what do you want to achief?

Comment: remove display:table from the #text

Comment: tell me what you want, why you are using `display:table`?

Comment: I found this somewhere as a workaround to vertically align the text in the button to the middle...

Comment: why aren't you using an input button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part 1:**
Remove the border:

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

**Part 2:**
Change the display of the button to `inline-block` (you may need to tweak the padding on top and bottom)

```
#button {
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Part 1 worked like a charm, thanks! Part 2 does work too, but this button loses his 100% height...

Comment: I also had to remove `.ui-btn-inner { display:block }`, you may want to change that to `inline`, as well.

Comment: @binoculars true, that's why I said to tweak the padding on top and bottom

Comment: @jackJoe hmm... seems like it only works when I use px (which is not ideal since the height is in %). When I use %, the button get's way to big...

Comment: you should be able to set a `max-height` or a `min-height` for the style like you did with the `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned that the button wasn't responding to the width the way that you had hoped.

```
#text {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:300px;
    left: 10%;
    right:10%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

if you only want it to be `300px` no matter what size everything else is, then set the

```
#text{
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

your text div is actually the one with the background that you are seeing.
your button is doing exactly what you told it to and has a max width of 300px but the containing div looks like part of the button,  not really sure why you need the containing text div,  but I suppose there is a reason.

with the previous answer and this code it will look like {in Chrome}

[image: button picture]

Comment: Got it to work 'till there... How to make it 100% high again?

Comment: you should be able to set a `max-height` or a `min-height` for the style like you did with the `max-width`

Comment: This does work, however, now my text is not verticaly in the middle anymore :(

Comment: there is a lot of divs and hidden spans,  you are just going to have to look at the box model and realize that each piece has it's settings, you might want to try some margins on the `.ui-btn-text` span.